# Script to download email from Gmail and save to a SQL server?

Tags: c#, .net, email, gmail

Does anyone know of a script to download email from Gmail and store it to a SQL server? (for backup purposes)

I am looking for a .NET solution (C#).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be pretty easy to write one yourself. Just connect via IMAP of Pop3 (there's .NET libraries for that already) then download the emails, and stick them in your database. A program like that would take an hour to write, tops, unless you require more features.

Comment: I guess the labels (category) information doesn't come through right?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail supports POP3, you can use this .NET client and get the emails that way, putting them in the database is trivial at that point:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx